# Accessing SharePoint Online sites via the unified API

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

The new unified Microsoft API is supposed to cover all Office365 products. However, I can't find any documentation on how to access SharePoint online sites and lists. Could somebody clarify how to do it?

If it's not possible, can I still use the old API? How do I do it? There's no more option to register a SharePoint Online app on Azure AD.

UPD: I’m writing a python application that needs to fetch some data from users’ SharePoint online sites. I need to register my app in Azure AD to implement authentication.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question but just in case it helps someone. This is now fully supported by the Microsoft Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint

You will need to register an application on either the v1.0 (Azure AD Administration portal > Enterprise Apps) or v2.0 (apps.dev.microsoft.com) Azure AD endpoints and some SharePoint permissions & consent. Once done, you need a bearer token once authenticated and you can use 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root to retrieve the root site, but if you want to get to a specific site you can use 
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}

There is currently no native way to simply list any and all sites (again, depending on user permissions this might vary user by user) but there is a small trick to get around this: by using the search method: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

This will effectively list all sites - except for ones that belong to O365 groups.

Hope this helps

Ben

Comment: Thanks great suggestion! but how is ?search=* even a small trick? it's exactly what I need (with a partial keyword added to the glob) and seems like a legitimate use.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the SharePoint 2013 REST API or work with the ClientContext.

Just get the AccessToken for the right RessourceId. If you use the DiscoveryClient it would be the rootsitecapability.ServiceResourceId.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain your answer in more detail please? I didn't really understand the part about getting the right ResourceId.

Comment: I working on a provider hosted app, it's a ASP.NET App on Azure which communicates with the different APIs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx In my case the ResourceId is the https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com so I can get the Token for this ressource and create the ClientContext Object to communicate with SP.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but your link was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint sites and lists are not yet available via Microsoft Graph. We are working on adding support for them in the near future. 
In the mean time you can call the SharePoint endpoint directly, to do this you can create an Office 365 trial account and associate it with you Azure subscription following information in this link: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/associate_account
Furthermore information about the SharePoint APIs is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  I'm trying to create an application in Azure Active Directory, so for example when i want to use Graph API, i'm adding the Microsoft graph, all good.
But i want to create an App for SharePoint online and i don't see the application previously called Office 365 SharePoint. How do I create an app in this case?

Comment: Do you have a license for SharePoint? you will only see the list of services that there are licenses for.

Comment: I have never developed for Microsoft products before, and I cannot find where this things are described in documentation. Could you please point me to a resource where ALL this is explained in detail? Obtaining a licence, registering an app, authentication, etc. Whatever I can find is either irrelevant or doesn't work.

Comment: How do I get this licence?? I can't start on the project without authentication. @Yina you're my only hope

Comment: You can create an Office 365 trial account and associate it with you Azure subscription following information in this link: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/associate_account

Comment: Thank you so much @Yina! This works! I'd never guess to look in graph api docs, as graph api is not for share point. If you update your answer, i'll gladly accept it.